# Catalyst global moose hash returning MIME type httpd/unix-directory

Tags: perl, hash, mime-types, moose, catalyst

I'm trying to create a [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) hash in my [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) app in `my_app.pm` so that I can access it globally:

```
has 'hash' => ( 
    is => 'rw', 
    isa => 'Hashref'
);
```

However, as soon as I try to add defaults:

```
has 'hash' => ( 
    is => 'rw', 
    isa => 'Hashref',
    default => sub { { 
        'key' => 'val',
      }
    },
);
```

Then I get this message in my chrome developer tools console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type httpd/unix-directory
```

whenever I try to load the page. Then my pages don't load correctly and try to force me to download an empty file whenever I load the page. Is it not possible to use a `Moose` hash with defaults in `my_app.pm`? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your base class already has a field by that name?

Comment: @ikegami no, it doesn't. Do you think if I were to use `__PACKAGE__->config` instead of a `Moose` hash that this would be an acceptable work around?

Comment: I don't understand the question (What's a "Moose hash"?!)

Comment: Why don't you properly debug this. See what's causing the message, and determine how you got into that situation.

Comment: @ikegami, I just mean when you define a `Moose` attribute as a `Hashref` by using `isa`.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for the help. I found out what the problem was and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have some kind of problem with the way your app is set up; you're seeing that error above when you should be seeing an error page.
2. Your default is invalid. `sub { 'key' => 'val' }` doesn't return a hashref; it returns a list of two items ('key' and 'val'). Try `default => sub { +{ 'key' => 'val' } }` instead.

Comment: gah, if you need to disambiguate, use `return` instead of `+`!

Comment: @hobbs, sorry, I entered my default incorrectly into stackoverflow, but I had it correctly in my app.

Comment: @hobbs @ikegami I tried changing it to what hobbs suggested, then I tried using `return` instead of `+`, however I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong, and unfortunately this is one of those 'doh' moments :)

When defining a `Moose` attribute as a hash, you have to do it as so:

```
has 'hash' => ( 
    is => 'rw', 
    isa => 'HashRef'
);
```

I accidentally misspelled `HashRef` and used `Hashref`. Thanks for all of the help! :)